# How to select parent pseudo-class from within child using scss

Tags: css, sass, ampersand

I'd like to select the parent using the following pattern.

I understand I could write this within the parent selector, but I'd like to know if it's possible to prefix the parent's pseudo class to the child from within the child selector.

JSX:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" />
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" />
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.parent {
    height: 100px;

    .child {
    // the goal is to write this so it produces the CSS output below, from 
    // within .child

        &:first-child & {
            height: 50px;
        }
    }
}
```

CSS [output]:

```
.parent:first-child .child {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Despite having found a solution, I'd still be curious to hear if there's a way to do this without re-writing the parent class name within the child.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So seems like this is really easy.  Whoops.

You just do the following:

SCSS:

```
.child {
    .parent:first-child & {
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

This probably looks silly, but for my situation, it's actually useful.

Comment: That's pretty cool you can do that in sass, thanks for showing the solution. However, I would avoid such practices on production, as it may become hard to read and maintain.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe isn't the most useful code but works:

**SASS**

```
.parent {
  $root: &;
  height: 100px;
  @at-root {
    .child {
      @at-root {
        #{$root}:first-child #{&} {
          height: 50px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.parent {
  height: 100px;
}
.parent:first-child .child {
  height: 50px;
}
```